# how to make graphql from model of mongoose?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, graphql

I am adding a certain object to the db using graphql and mongodb.

I am using the same technique to add an object to the db but this certain object contains a nested one.

- package.json

```
{
  "name": "workplaces",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "app.js",
  "author": "younes",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon app02.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-graphql": "^0.12.0",
    "graphql": "^15.4.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.11.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7"
  }
}
```

- **model location** mongodb models for both purchase and use data

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const locationSchema = new Schema(
    {
        locationName:[
            {
                lang:{
                    type: String,
                    enum:["en","fr"],
                    required: true
                },
                text:{
                    type: String,
                    required: true
                }
            }
        ],
        locationType:{
            type:String,
            enum:["clinic","laboratory","radiology"],
            required: true
        },
        imageUrl:{
            type:[String]
        },
        locationMap: {
            type: {
                type: String, 
                enum: ['Point'],
                required: true
            },
            coordinates: {
                type: [Number],
                required: true
            },
        },
        owner: {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'User'
        }
    },
    {
        timestamps: true,
    }
);

module.exports  = mongoose.model('location', locationSchema);
```

- **graphql**

```
const express=require('express');
const graphqlHTTP=require('express-graphql').graphqlHTTP;
const {buildSchema}=require('graphql');
const mongoose=require('mongoose');
const bcrypt=require('bcryptjs');

const User=require('./models/user');

const Location=require('./models/location');


const app=express();
app.use(express.json());

app.use('/graphql',
    graphqlHTTP({
        schema:buildSchema(`

            type LocationName{
                lang:String!
                text:String!
            }
            input InputLocationName{
                lang:String!
                text:String!
            }

            type LocationMap{
                type:String!
                coordinates:[Float!]
            }
            input InputLocationMap{
                type:String!
                coordinates:[Float!]
            }

            type Location{
                _id:ID!
                locationName:[LocationName!]
                locationType:String!
                imageUrl:[String!]
                locationMap:LocationMap!
                owner:User!
            }
            input InputLocation{
                locationName:[LocationName!]!
                locationType:String!
                imageUrl:[String!]
                locationMap:LocationMap!
            }
           
           
            type User{
                _id:ID!
                email:String!
                password:String
            }
            input InputUser{
                email:String!
                password:String!
            }

            type RootQuery{
                users:[User!]!
                locations: [Location!]!
            }
            type RootMutation{
                createUser(inputUser:InputUser): User
                createLocation(inputLocation:InputLocation): Location
            }
            schema{
                query: RootQuery
                mutation: RootMutation 
            }
        `),
        rootValue:{
            users:()=>{
                return User.find()
                .then(users=>{
                    console.log(users)
                    return users
                })
                .catch(err=>{
                    throw err;
                })
            },
            createLocation:(args)=>{
                return User.findOne({_id:"6002cff9d32ceb25ac9e9c7e"})
                .then(user=>{
                    if (!user) {
                        throw new Error('User dont found.')
                    }
                    else{
                        const location=new Location(
                            { 
                                locationName:args.inputLocation.LocationName ,
                                locationType:args.inputLocation.locationType,
                                imageUrl:args.inputLocation.imageUrl,
                                locationMap:args.inputLocation.LocationMap,
                                owner:"6002cff9d32ceb25ac9e9c7e"
                            }
                        );
                        return location
                        .save()
                        .then(result=>{
                            console.log(result)
                            return result
                        })
                        .catch((err)=>{
                            throw err;
                        })
                    }
                    
                })
               
            },
            createUser:(args)=>{
                return User.findOne({email:args.userInput.email})
                .then(user=>{
                    if (user) {
                        throw new Error('User exists already.')
                    }
                    else{
                        return bcrypt
                        .hash(args.userInput.password,12)
                        .then(hashPassword=>{
                            const user=new User(
                                {
                                    email:args.userInput.email,
                                    password:hashPassword
                                }
                            );
                            return user
                            .save()
                            .then(result=>{
                                return { ...result._doc,password:null}
                            })
                            .catch((err)=>{throw err;})
                        })
                        .catch((err)=>{
                            throw err;
                        })
                    }
                    
                })
                
            },
            
        },
        graphiql:true
    })
);


uri=process.env.URI
mongoose.connect(uri,
                {useNewUrlParser:true
                    ,useCreateIndex:true
                    , useUnifiedTopology:true
                    })
    .then(()=>{
        console.log("database connected")
        app.listen(5000);
    })
    .catch((err)=>{
        console.log(err)
    })
```

- Here is my current graphQL query:

```
mutation{
  createLocation(inputLocation:{
      locationName:[{lang:"en",text:"sad",isShow:true}],
      locationType:"clinic",
      imageUrl:["/images/01.png"],
      locationMap:{
        type:"Point",
        coordinates:[2342342,2342345]
      }
  })
  {
    _id
  }
}
```

> ERROR

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "The type of InputLocation.locationName must be Input Type but got: [LocationName!]!.",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 33,
          "column": 30
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "message": "The type of InputLocation.locationMap must be Input Type but got: LocationMap!.",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 37,
          "column": 29
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Please help, thanks!

Comment: any complex types in `input InputLocation{` should be input types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **graphql**

```
const express=require('express');
const graphqlHTTP=require('express-graphql').graphqlHTTP;
const {buildSchema}=require('graphql');
const mongoose=require('mongoose');
const bcrypt=require('bcryptjs');
const User=require('./models/user');
const Location=require('./models/location');


const app=express();
app.use(express.json());


app.use('/graphql',
    graphqlHTTP({
        schema:buildSchema(`

            type LocationName{
                lang:String!
                text:String!
            }
            input InputLocationName{
                lang:String!
                text:String!
            }

            type LocationMap{
                type:String!
                coordinates:[Float!]
            }
            input InputLocationMap{
                type:String!
                coordinates:[Float!]!
            }

            type Location{
                _id:ID!
                locationName:[LocationName!]!
                locationType:String!
                imageUrl:[String!]
                locationMap:LocationMap!
                owner:User!
            }
            input InputLocation_otherItems{             
                locationType:String!
                imageUrl:[String!]
            }
           
           
            type User{
                _id:ID!
                email:String!
                password:String
            }
            input InputUser{
                email:String!
                password:String!
            }

            type RootQuery{
                users:[User!]!
                locations: [Location!]!
            }
            type RootMutation{
                createUser(inputUser:InputUser): User
                createLocation( inputLocation_otherItems:InputLocation_otherItems
                                inputLocationName:InputLocationName
                                inputLocationMap:InputLocationMap): Location
            }
            schema{
                query: RootQuery
                mutation: RootMutation 
            }
        `),
        rootValue:{
            users:()=>{
                return User.find()
                .then(users=>{
                    console.log(users)
                    return users
                })
                .catch(err=>{
                    throw err;
                })
            },
            createLocation:(args)=>{
                return User.findOne({_id:"6002cff9d32ceb25ac9e9c7e"})
                .then(user=>{
                    if (!user) {
                        throw new Error('User dont found.')
                    }
                    else{
                        const location=new Location(
                            { 
                                locationType:args.inputLocation_otherItems.locationType,
                                imageUrl:args.inputLocation_otherItems.imageUrl,
                                locationName:[args.inputLocationName] ,
                                locationMap:args.inputLocationMap,
                                owner:"6002cff9d32ceb25ac9e9c7e"
                            }
                        );
                        return location
                        .save()
                        .then(result=>{
                            return result
                        })
                        .catch((err)=>{
                            throw err;
                        })
                    }
                    
                })
               
            },
            createUser:(args)=>{
                return User.findOne({email:args.userInput.email})
                .then(user=>{
                    if (user) {
                        throw new Error('User exists already.')
                    }
                    else{
                        return bcrypt
                        .hash(args.userInput.password,12)
                        .then(hashPassword=>{
                            const user=new User(
                                {
                                    email:args.userInput.email,
                                    password:hashPassword
                                }
                            );
                            return user
                            .save()
                            .then(result=>{
                                return { ...result._doc,password:null}
                            })
                            .catch((err)=>{throw err;})
                        })
                        .catch((err)=>{
                            throw err;
                        })
                    }
                    
                })
                
            },
            
        },
        graphiql:true
    })
);


uri=process.env.URI
mongoose.connect(uri,
                {useNewUrlParser:true
                    ,useCreateIndex:true
                    , useUnifiedTopology:true
                    })
    .then(()=>{
        console.log("database connected")
        app.listen(5000);
    })
    .catch((err)=>{
        console.log(err)
    })
```

> **Mutation**

```
mutation{
  createLocation(
    inputLocation_otherItems:{  locationType:"clinic"
                                imageUrl:["/images/01.png"]
    }
    
    inputLocationName:{ lang:"en"
                        text:"Life Clinic"
    }

    inputLocationMap:{type:"Point"
                      coordinates:[2342342,2342345]
    }
  )
  {
    locationName{lang
                 text
    }
    locationType
    imageUrl
    locationMap{type 
                coordinates
    }
   
  }
}
```

> Result

```
{
  "data": {
    "createLocation": {
      "locationName": [
        {
          "lang": "en",
          "text": "Life Clinic"
        }
      ],
      "locationType": "clinic",
      "imageUrl": [
        "/images/01.png"
      ],
      "locationMap": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          2342342,
          2342345
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `input InputLocation{
                locationName:[InputLocationName!]!
                locationType:String!
                imageUrl:[String!]
                locationMap:InputLocationMap!
            }`